# Fixing File Access Permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, macos-catalina, errno

I am a longtime *FoxPro Windows developer* and Mac permissions are new to me. Though I suspect that **macOS Catalina** is causing lots of people problems.

**Environment - Thonny with Python 3.8**

I am writing my first program and trying to get a list of files in a directory -

```
files = os.listdir(direc)
```

I am getting,

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted ...

I have tried granting full disk access to Python, Thonny & Terminal as suggested in other posts, but no help.

What should I do?

Comment: Try saving a script into or load one from this directory (File => Save as / File => Open). With this you would signal to OS that you allow Thonny to use this directory. See https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/813 for more info.

Comment: That did it! Thanks.